# GraphQL Editing Entry adds new Entry

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, graphql-js

Im still working on my contact book. I was able to get it working like i wanted it to. But if i edit entrys it makes a new entry.

My database wants an "key" for every entry. As you'll see in my code i create this key with "Vorname + Nachname + n (DateandTime)".

I added DateandTime to avoid an error when adding a second person with the same name(same key). If i add an entry with the same key i get an error). If i leave the key empty i also get an error.

But with this code it always adds an person if i try to edit one. How can i avoid this?

Thanks in advance for your Answers

Code:

```
    import React from 'react';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { useMutation } from '@apollo/client';
import {
  Button,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  Label,
  Modal,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalBody,
  ModalFooter,
} from 'reactstrap';
import { Form as FinalForm, Field } from 'react-final-form';

import client from '../../../../apollo';
import { GET_POSTS } from './PostViewer';




const SUBMIT_POST = gql`
mutation (
$key: String!, 
$Namegql: String,
$Vornamegql: String,
$Quellegql: String,
$Artikelgql: String,
$Landgql: String,
$Ortgql: String,
$Telgql: String,
$Mobilgql: String,
$EMailgql: String,
$Whatsappgql: Boolean,
$Telegramgql: Boolean,
$Notizengql: String,
$Geschlechtgql: String,
){
  createInteressent(parentId: 1266, key: $key, published: true, input: {
Name: $Namegql,
Vorname: $Vornamegql,
Quelle: $Quellegql,
Artikel: $Artikelgql,
Land: $Landgql,
Ort: $Ortgql,
Tel: $Telgql,
Mobil: $Mobilgql,
EMail: $EMailgql,
Whatsapp: $Whatsappgql,
Telegram: $Telegramgql,
Notizen: $Notizengql,
Geschlecht: $Geschlechtgql,
}) {
    success
    message
    output(defaultLanguage: "de") {
      id
    }
  }
}
`;




const PostEditor = ({ node, onClose }) => (
  <FinalForm
    onSubmit={async ({ id, Name, Vorname, Quelle, Artikel, Land, Ort, Tel, Mobil, EMail, Whatsapp, Telegram, Notizen, Geschlecht }) => {
      const input = { id, Name, Vorname, Quelle, Artikel, Land, Ort, Tel, Mobil, EMail, Whatsapp, Telegram, Notizen, Geschlecht };
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.toLocaleString();
    const key = Vorname + Name + n;
    
    const Namegql = Name;
    const Vornamegql = Vorname;
    const Quellegql = Quelle;
    const Artikelgql = Artikel;
    const Landgql = Land;
    const Ortgql = Ort;
    const Telgql = Tel;
    const Mobilgql = Mobil;
    const EMailgql = EMail;
    const Whatsappgql = Whatsapp;
    const Telegramgql = Telegram;
    const Notizengql = Notizen;
    const Geschlechtgql = Geschlecht;
        await client.mutate({
        variables: { 
input, 
key, 
Namegql, 
Vornamegql, 
Quellegql, 
Artikelgql, 
Landgql, 
Ortgql, 
Telgql, 
Mobilgql, 
EMailgql, 
Whatsappgql, 
Telegramgql, 
Notizengql, 
Geschlechtgql
},
        mutation: SUBMIT_POST,
        refetchQueries: () => [{ query: GET_POSTS }],
});

      onClose();
    }}
    initialValues={node}
    render={({ handleSubmit, pristine, invalid }) => (
      <Modal isOpen toggle={onClose}>
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <ModalHeader toggle={onClose}>
           {node.id ? 'Eintrag bearbeiten' : 'Neuer Eintrag'}
          </ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
     <div>
            <label>Name</label>
            <Field
        required
              name="Name"
              component="input"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Vorname"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Vorname</label>
            <Field
              name="Vorname"
              component="input"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Vorname"
            />
          </div>
            <div>
              <Label>Quelle</Label>
              <Field
                name="Quelle"
                component="input"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Quelle"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Label>Artikel</Label>
              <Field                
                name="Artikel"
                component="input"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Artikel"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Label>Land</Label>
              <Field   
                name="Land"
                component="input"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Land"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Label>Ort</Label>
              <Field
                name="Ort"
                component="input"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Ort"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Label>Tel.</Label>
              <Field          
                name="Tel"
                component="input"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Tel."
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Label>Mobil</Label>
              <Field           
                name="Mobil"
                component="input"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Mobil"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Label>E-Mail</Label>
              <Field
                name="EMail"
                component="input"
              type="text"
              placeholder="E-Mail"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Label>Whatsapp</Label>
              <Field
                name="Whatsapp"
                component="input"
        type="checkbox"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Label>Telegram</Label>
              <Field         
                name="Telegram"
                component="input"
        type="checkbox"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Label>Notizen</Label>
              <Field        
                name="Notizen"
                className="form-control"
                component="textarea"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Label>Geschlecht</Label>
              <div>
              <label>
                <Field
                  name="Geschlecht"
                  component="input"
                  type="radio"
                  value="Männlich"
                />{' '}
                Männlich
              </label>
              <label>
                <Field
                  name="Geschlecht"
                  component="input"
                  type="radio"
                  value="Weiblich"
                />{' '}
                Weiblich
              </label>
              <label>
                <Field
                  name="Geschlecht"
                  component="input"
                  type="radio"
                  value="Divers"
                />{' '}
                Divers
              </label>
            </div>
            </div>
          </ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <Button type="submit" disabled={pristine} color="primary">Speichern</Button>
            <Button color="secondary" onClick={onClose}>Cancel</Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </Form>
      </Modal>
    )}
  />
);

export default PostEditor;
```

Comment: mutation name is '**create**Interessent', why it should work as update? renaming variables just to pass them as variable is ... a joke ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @xadm i found a solution and cleaned up my code :) -> renaming variables :D
Everything is working fine now.

```
import React from "react";
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/client";
import {
  Button,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  Label,
  Modal,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalBody,
  ModalFooter
} from "reactstrap";
import { Form as FinalForm, Field } from "react-final-form";

import client from "./apollo";
import { GET_POSTS } from "./PostViewer";

const UPDATE_ENTRY = 
gql`
  mutation(
   
    $idgql: Int!
    $Name: String
    $Vorname: String
    $Quelle: String
    $Artikel: String
    $Land: String
    $Ort: String
    $Tel: String
    $Mobil: String
    $EMail: String
    $URL: String
    $Whatsapp: Boolean
    $Telegram: Boolean
    $Notizen: String
    $Geschlecht: String
  ) {
    updateInteressent(
      id: $idgql
      input: {
        Name: $Name
        Vorname: $Vorname
        Quelle: $Quelle
        Artikel: $Artikel
        Land: $Land
        Ort: $Ort
        Tel: $Tel
        Mobil: $Mobil
        EMail: $EMail
        URL: $URL
        Whatsapp: $Whatsapp
        Telegram: $Telegram
        Notizen: $Notizen
        Geschlecht: $Geschlecht
      }
    ) {
      success
      message
      output(defaultLanguage: "de") {
        id
      }
    }
  }
`;

const NEW_ENTRY = gql`
 mutation (
$key: String!, 
$Name: String,
$Vorname: String,
$Quelle: String,
$Artikel: String,
$Land: String,
$Ort: String,
$Tel: String,
$Mobil: String,
$EMail: String,
$Whatsapp: Boolean,
$Telegram: Boolean,
$Notizen: String,
$Geschlecht: String,
){
  createInteressent(parentId: 1266, key: $key, published: true, input: {
Name: $Name,
Vorname: $Vorname,
Quelle: $Quelle,
Artikel: $Artikel,
Land: $Land,
Ort: $Ort,
Tel: $Tel,
Mobil: $Mobil,
EMail: $EMail,
Whatsapp: $Whatsapp,
Telegram: $Telegram,
Notizen: $Notizen,
Geschlecht: $Geschlecht,
}) {
    success
    message
    output(defaultLanguage: "de") {
      id
    }
  }
}
`;


const PostEditor = ({ node, onClose }) => (
    
  <FinalForm
    onSubmit={async ({
      id,
      Name,
      Vorname,
      Quelle,
      Artikel,
      Land,
      Ort,
      Tel,
      Mobil,
      EMail,
      URL,
      Whatsapp,
      Telegram,
      Notizen,
      Geschlecht
    }) => {
      var d = new Date();
      var n = d.toLocaleString();
      const key = Vorname + Name + n;
      const idgql = node.id;
      const ENTRY = (node.id ? UPDATE_ENTRY : NEW_ENTRY);
      await client.mutate({
        variables: {
          key,
          Name,
          idgql,
          Vorname,
          Quelle,
          Artikel,
          Land,
          Ort,
          Tel,
          Mobil,
          EMail,
          URL,
          Whatsapp,
          Telegram,
          Notizen,
          Geschlecht,

        },
    
        mutation: ENTRY,

        refetchQueries: () => [{ query: GET_POSTS }]
      });

      onClose();
    }}
    initialValues={node}
    render={({ handleSubmit, pristine, invalid }) => (
      <Modal isOpen toggle={onClose}>
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <ModalHeader toggle={onClose}>
            {node.id ? "Eintrag bearbeiten" : "Neuer Eintrag"}

          </ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            <div>
              <label>Name</label>
              <Field
                required
                name="Name"
                component="input"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Vorname"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label>Vorname</label>
              <Field
                name="Vorname"
                component="input"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Vorname"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Label>Quelle</Label>
              <Field name="Quelle" component="select">
                <option />
                <option value="eBay-Kleinanzeigen">eBay-Kleinanzeigen</option>
                <option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
                <option value="Twitter">Twitter</option>
                <option value="Instagram">Instagram</option>
                <option value="Mundpropaganda">Mundpropaganda</option>
                <option value="Sonstiges">Sonstiges (siehe Notizen)</option>
              </Field>
            </div>
            <div>
              <Label>Artikel</Label>
              <Field
                name="Artikel"
                component="input"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Artikel"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Label>Land</Label>
              <Field
                name="Land"
                component="input"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Land"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Label>Ort</Label>
              <Field
                name="Ort"
                component="input"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Ort"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Label>Tel.</Label>
              <Field
                name="Tel"
                component="input"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Tel."
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Label>Mobil</Label>
              <Field
                name="Mobil"
                component="input"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Mobil"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Label>E-Mail</Label>
              <Field
                name="EMail"
                component="input"
                type="text"
                placeholder="E-Mail"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Label>URL</Label>
              <Field
                name="URL"
                component="input"
                type="text"
                placeholder="URL"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Label>Whatsapp</Label>
              <Field name="Whatsapp" component="input" type="checkbox" />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Label>Telegram</Label>
              <Field name="Telegram" component="input" type="checkbox" />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Label>Notizen</Label>
              <Field
                name="Notizen"
                className="form-control"
                component="textarea"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Label>Geschlecht</Label>
              <div>
                <label>
                  <Field
                    name="Geschlecht"
                    component="input"
                    type="radio"
                    value="Männlich"
                  />{" "}
                  Männlich
                </label>
                <label>
                  <Field
                    name="Geschlecht"
                    component="input"
                    type="radio"
                    value="Weiblich"
                  />{" "}
                  Weiblich
                </label>
                <label>
                  <Field
                    name="Geschlecht"
                    component="input"
                    type="radio"
                    value="Divers"
                  />{" "}
                  Divers
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <Button type="submit" disabled={pristine} color="primary">
              Speichern
            </Button>
            <Button color="secondary" onClick={onClose}>
              Cancel
            </Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </Form>
      </Modal>
    )}
  />
);

export default PostEditor;
```

Comment: still to much code ... what is the [API docs] type of `input` param of these mutations?

Comment: @xadm what do you mean with that? Should i put my input variables into an array?

Comment: you already have a input object - input type (like review in https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#input-types ) for grouping fields named `input`- read its type from API docs/specs

Comment: @xadm The input type you mean was left from the original code. Actually i did't get it to work so my code was the workaround.

Original CODE:

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/10/11/build-simple-web-app-with-express-react-graphql

Comment: API/BE - do you have a playground? server types, `updateInteressent` mutation defs/specs - argument types?

Comment: my playground is my pc @localhost, as my server is http and i get a cross origin error on other playgrounds.